# "Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

I'm using python 2.7 have the code below to connect sql instances

```
class SqlConnector:
    def __init__(self, driver, sqlserver_ip, database, **kwargs):
        if 'port' in kwargs:
            conn_string = 'DRIVER='+ driver + ';SERVER='+ sqlserver_ip +';PORT=' + kwargs['port'] + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';trusted_connection=yes;'
        else:
            conn_string = 'DRIVER='+ driver + ';SERVER='+ sqlserver_ip + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';trusted_connection=yes;'
        print conn_string
        self.conn = pypyodbc.connect(conn_string)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def query(self, query_string):
        self.cur.execute(query_string)
        return

    def get_all_table_columns(self):
        columns = [column[0] for column in self.cur.description]
        return columns

    def get_all_table_rows(self):
        rows = self.cur.fetchall()
        return rows

    def __repr__(self):
        conn_string = 'DRIVER='+ driver + ';SERVER='+ sqlserver_ip + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';trusted_connection=yes;'
        return conn_string

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.conn or self.cur:
            # close cursor
            self.cur.close()
            # close connection
            self.conn.close()
```

My SQL instance is like "hostname\PEWKA", but error below saying

> (u'08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL
>   Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF]. ')

is this the correct way to connect SQL instance using pypyodbc? can't really find too much info out of it.

Anyone can shed some light will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Connecting by instance name

Provide the server name and instance name separated by a backslash, e.g., `SERVER=hostname\PEWKA`. Do not supply a port number. If the SQL Server instance is on a remote machine then the SQL Server Browser service must be running on that machine.

#### Connecting by port number

Provide the server name and port number separated by a comma, e.g., `SERVER=hostname,49242`. Do not supply the instance name. Note also that the SQL Server ODBC drivers do not support a `PORT=` parameter in the connection string.